# Batch inserts and updates to table from C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have an application written in C#. The app writes records to a table in a SQL database. The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products]
(
    [Id] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
    [ReferenceNumber] [INT] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
    [OnHand] [INT] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Please note that the `Id` field is a `Guid` that is sent from the application. The `ReferenceNumber` is an auto-incremented field generated by the database. I'm writing records to the table via the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductSave] 
    (@id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
     @name NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @onHand INT) 
AS
    DECLARE @referenceNumber INT

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Products WHERE [Id] = @id) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Products]
        SET [Name] = @name,
            [OnHand] = @onHand
        WHERE [Id] = @id
    END 
    ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Products] ([Id], [Name], [OnHand])
        VALUES (@id, @name, @onHand)
    END

    SET @referenceNumber = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    RETURN @referenceNumber
GO
```

The stored procedure returns the `ReferenceNumber` of the product that was inserted or updated. I need that `ReferenceNumber` in my C# code. At the same time, I need to send insert / update a batch of records at once.

At this time, my C# code looks like this:

```
public static void SaveProducts(List<Product> products)
{
     var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["productDb"].ConnectionString;

     using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString)
     {
         using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
         {
             cmd.Connection = conn;
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
             cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[ProductSave]";

             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier));
             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@onHand", SqlDbType.Int));

             foreach (var product in products)
             {
                 cmd.Parameters[0].Value = product.Id;
                 cmd.Parameters[1].Value = product.Name;
                 cmd.Parameters[2].Value = product.OnHand;
             }

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

             // How do I assign the ReferenceNumber to each Product instance?
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this, there's some weird behavior. It doesn't seem all products get saved. Why would that be? At the same time, and I believe related, is how do I get the ReferenceNumbers from the database and assign them to their products in code?

I really need to save the products in a batch. I can't save them one-at-a-time. At the same time, I do need to get the `ReferenceNumber` back from the database and assign it to the `Product` for use in code. What am I missing / doing wrong?

Comment: You are rewriting command parameters in foreach loop and only last product gets saved

Comment: That's a misuse of RETURN but you could access the value by setting the parameter direction of `@id` to `ReturnValue`. It is more appropriate to use `Output`. Not your only problem, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: For batching guidance [see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performing-batch-operations-using-dataadapters)

Comment: A Stored Procedure doesn't return what you think it returns. Are you instead referring to an OUTPUT variable? Research that.